# NodeJS / Express all requests to specific path

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, path

I'm not looking to serve a static folder/files. That being cleared, here is my issue:

I have a Login page, and after the user has been verified, I create a session.
Based on this session, I want to give the client access/denial to every request they make to the url path *example.com/admin*

Why? I have API calls to this url but also a file inside /public/admin/dashboard.html (and yes the /public folder is served as a static folder) - and all of these incoming requests should just be possible from clients with verified sessions.

I tried to use `app.get("/admin/*",...` but that seems also to affect all the other domains with get requests:

```
app.get("/admin/*", function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.email !== undefined) {
      console.log("User is verified to access");
      return res.redirect("/admin/dashboard.html");
    } else {
      console.log("Failed: User not verified, redirect to 404");
      return res.redirect("/404.html");
    }
  })
```

And the code above is called before the

```
app.use(express.static("./public"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function to validate users to allow `/admin/*` route and then use it as follows:

```
function validate(req, res, next){
  //logic to verify user, validate session
  if(user is allowed to access){
    next();//Proceed to handle the request
  }
  else{
    //end request with 401 as unauthorized
    res.status(401).send();
  }
}
app.get("/admin/*", validate, function(req, res) {
    //Actual response to send
  });
```

You can use validate functionality for any requests which need authorization.

UPDATE: My bad. `/admin` checks for the URLs ending with `/admin` only. Hence, `/admin/dashboard.html` won't work. If you want the authorization check to all URLs that have `/admin` in the them, then regex pattern can be used like `/admin/*` and then send response once validated.  Hope this explains your query.

Comment: This seems to work, however, whats the difference between validating withing the app.get (like i did it) and using a function (your way).

Comment: For other routes you want to protect, you need not repeat the code for authorization. You can simply re-use this validate function(kinda middleware) for all other routes and keep actual route handling clean and simple.

Comment: I know that, but my questions was what is different between these two functions that one works and the other doesnt

Comment: Try without /* in your code like app.get('/admin', function(){})... it should also work

Comment: Just realised, your answer also just works with `/admin` requests, but not with `/admin/dahsboard.html`

Comment: Updated answer is what I had in the beginning but adding a middleware did it. However, it seems to me that both should work, with and without middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're having problems with the wildcard url matching, or serving up the static file. Here is an example on how to use a middleware to take care of the authorization and then serve up the static file from a specific endpoint.

It's not a copy paste to solve your problem, but I hope this might help you find a solution.

```
const authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.sess.email === undefined) {
    return res.redirect('/404/.html');
  }
  next();
}

app.get('/admin/dashboard.html', auhenticate, function(req, res) {
    console.log('User is verified to access');
    return res.sendFile([File location for dashboard.html],
                        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}});
});
```

Comment: Hm.. not sure but doesnt this solution block access to e.g. /index.html which should be public?

Comment: However, this is also the solution, the other just seems more complete

Comment: good. I did not understand why you would redirect to /admin/dashboard.html if you entered /admin/dashboard.html in the url. It would be a loop in my mind. The solution provided removes this by redirecting to a new location when you enter /admin, but you should test with /admin/dashboard.html to see that you cant access it..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lifetimeLearner007 and @R.Gulbrandsen who lead me into the right direction.
For anyone following up, a combination of both solved it (but dont know why)

```
app.get("/admin/*", validateUser, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Validated");
    next();
  })

function validateUser(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.email)
    if (req.session.email !== undefined) {
      console.log("User is verified to access");
      next();
    } else {
      console.log("Failed: User not verified, redirect to 404");
      return res.redirect("/404.html");
    }
  }
```